# Laravel - AJAX Search works for Input but not Select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been having a little problem. I am trying to create a filter for my database. So far I have come up with this:

**Blade File:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Name, NORAD or ID"></input>

<select name="filtername" id="filtername">
    <option value="none"></option>
    <option value="Falcon">Falcon</option>
    <option value="rb">R/B</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript AJAX Call:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    $value = $(this).val();
    delay(function() {
        if ('#search'.length > 3) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{$launchsitename->site_code}}',
                data: {
                    'search': $value
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#launchsatdisplay').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 300);
});

$("#filtername").change(function() {
    var filtername = $(this).val();
    var dataString = "filtername=" + filtername;
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{$launchsitename->site_code}}",
        data: {
            'search': dataString
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#launchsatdisplay').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

**Controller:**

```
if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $output="";
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
            ->where(function($q) use ($request) {
                $q->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('object_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
            })
            ->where('site', $site_code)->get();
        if ($launchsitesatellite)
        {
            $output .='<tr>'.
            '<th>'.'Satellite Name'.'</th>'.
            '<th>'.'NORAD ID'.'</th>'.
            '<th>'.'Object Type'.'</th>'.
            '<th>'.'Launch Date'.'</th>'.
            '<th>'.'Country'.'</th>'.
            '<th>'.'Object ID'.'</th>'.
            '<tr>';
            foreach ($launchsitesatellite as $key => $launchsitesatellites) {
            $output .='<tr>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->satname.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->norad_cat_id.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->object_type.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->launch.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->country.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->object_id.'</td>'.
                    '</tr>';
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
    else {
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('site', $site_code)->Paginate(40);
        return view('pages/launchsite-filter', compact('launchsites', 'launchsitesatellite'));
    }
```

This code is for making an AJAX call to my controller and getting the results from the database. The code posted above works perfectly for the `input`. I am able to search the database with ease. The only problem is with the `select`. Whenever I select an option, it returns no results. I am guessing there is something wrong with the way I programmed the `select` in my controller, as I don't think the Javascript would be causing the problem.

The `select` should be reading the `satname` column in my database called `satellites` and returning the filtered results.

Would somebody be able to shed some light on why the `select` is not working or where the error in my code is?

Comment: `'search': dataString`. How do you think what is this?

Comment: `$request->filterfalcon`? This is what?

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry - That was my attempt at trying to get it to work. I have removed it now.

Comment: I repeat - what is `'search': dataString`?

Comment: @u_mulder `'search': dataString` means that it is taking the `var dataString = "filtername="+filtername;` value which contains the the selected option.

Comment: So do you understand that `$request->search` has value `filtername=rb`, for example. Do you really expect search to find by this "word"?

Answer (score 0):

modify your ajax call code for select box as below

```
$("#filtername").change(function() {

    var dataString = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{$launchsitename->site_code}}",
        data: {
            'search': dataString
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#launchsatdisplay').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```